# Could this task be solved using more functional approach?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, polynomial-math

I'm writing simple polynomial-related library for my own needs. As for now, I'm working with just the polynomials in polynomial basis over GF(2), so they are represented simply as

```
case class Polynomial(coeffs: BitSet)
```

So I can just write something like

```
Polynomial(BitSet(0,1,2))
```

to represent

```
(x^2 + x + 1)
```

Now, I'm particularly proud about my multiplication function:

```
def *(that: Polynomial): Polynomial = Polynomial {
    coeffs.foldLeft(BitSet.empty) { case (acc, i) => acc ^ that.coeffs.map(i +) }
}
```

But as for now, all my efforts to express reduction by some other polynomial modulo didn't show any similar result. I do indeed understand that division is somewhat more complex, but I currently have very, very dirty recursive solution and I don't like it at all.
What I currently have is something like what follows (don't forget we are in GF(2)). (UPD: Simplified code to make it runnable outside class)

```
  def foo(thisSet: BitSet, thatSet: BitSet): BitSet = {
    var ts = thisSet
    while (!ts.isEmpty && ts.max >= thatSet.max) {
      ts = ts ^ thatSet.map(_ - thatSet.max + ts.max)
    }
    ts
  }
```

It works fine (though I didn't write any test so far), but I'd like to have something neat (tail-recursive at most, but desirably just using folds/maps/reduces.

Answer (score 0):

You could always write simple loop in a recursive manner

exemple with your foo function :

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
def fooRec(thisSet : BitSet, thatSet : BitSet) : BitSet = {
    @tailrec def loop(acc : BitSet) : BitSet = {
        if (!acc.isEmpty && acc.max >= thatSet.max) loop(acc ^ thatSet.map(_ - thatSet.max + acc.max))
        else acc
    }
    loop(thisSet)
}                                         //> fooRec: (thisSet: scala.collection.BitSet, thatSet: scala.collection.BitSet)
                                          //| scala.collection.BitSet

foo(BitSet(1, 2, 0), BitSet(3, 0, 1))           //> res0: scala.collection.BitSet = BitSet(0, 1, 2)
fooRec(BitSet(1, 2, 0), BitSet(3, 0, 1))        //> res1: scala.collection.BitSet = BitSet(0, 1, 2)
```

You can see that the `var ts` is the parameter of the inner recursive function `loop` and the while is now just an `if`.

Tail recursive function and while loop are almost identical in performance and readability, in my opinion. you can choose the style that suits you best.

Personally i don't think this version is more dirty than the while version.